# CUDA - Simple matrix addition/sum operation

Tags: matrix, cuda, sum, cublas

This should be very simple but I could not find an exhaustive answer:

I need to perform A+B = C with matrices, where A and B are two matrices of unknown size (they could be 2x2 or 20.000x20.000 as greatest value)

Should I use CUBLAS with Sgemm function to calculate?

I need the maximum speed achievable so I thought of CUBLAS library which should be well-optimized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any sort of technical computing, you should *always* use optimized libraries when available.  Existing libraries, used by hundreds of other people, are going to be better tested and better optimized than anything you do yourself, and the time you don't spend writing (and debugging, and optimizing) that function yourself can be better spent working on the actual high-level problem you want to solve instead of re-discovering things other people have already implemented.    This is just basic specialization of labour stuff; focus on the compute problem you want to solve, and let people who spend their days professionally writing GPGPU matrix routines do that for you.

Only when you are sure that existing libraries don't do what you need -- maybe they solve too general a problem, or make certain assumptions that don't hold in your case -- should you roll your own.

I agree with the others that in this particular case, the operation is pretty straightforward and it's feasible to DIY; but if you're going to be doing anything else with those matricies once you're done adding them, you'd be best off using optimized BLAS routines for whatever platform you're on.

Comment: Okay, I'll use CUBLAS. To answer Eric too: I need them also for matrix multiplications (but that wasn't the topic of the question)

Comment: -1: Feasible to DIY?  This is the "Hello world!" application for CUDA.

Comment: He's also using CUBLAS for matrix multiplication.  And he's doing this for *real* *work*, not to learn CUDA; he's trying to get real stuff done.  Hello world or not, there is still a significant speed difference depending on block size, etc.  So yes, he _should_ use optimized libraries.

Comment: Quick - is the fastest way to do this have one output per thread, or two, or more?  Is that true for both single and double precision?  How does that answer, and performance overall, vary with blocksize?  Gridsize?  How do _those_ choices vary with input size? Which of all of those combinations should the OP use for optimal performance?  For production code, the OP could go through all those combinations, spending days learning lots about CUDA and the architecture, occasionally debugging -- or he could, you know, use the library he's got which already works fast, and get his real work done.

Comment: @Jonathan Dursi: I would agree with you if all the OP wanted to do was take advantage of the GPU for a performance boost.  He explicitly states though that he needs the "maximum speed achievable".  If this is truly the goal, then hand tuning CUDA code for the specific problem (and target hardware) is the only way to go.

Comment: And what do you think the odds are that a beginning CUDA programmer is going to beat the CUBLAS saxpy implemnetation?  Or the matrix multiplication stuff he's doing?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do would be trivial to implement in CUDA and will be bandwidth limited.

Comment: It's not so trivial for me though. What I mean is: I can write code to compute the matrices sum, but how to choose the grid dimension? I know that blocks should have a number of threads multiple of the semiwarp, but this isn't enough.. I would end having a large number of idle threads. I'm not sure on how to proceed

Comment: Unless you have a complicated memory structure for your matrices, this basically boils down to vector addition.  There is an example of summing two vectors in the programming guide.  The only extension you would need to consider is the case where your last warp partially goes beyond the end of the vector, which is also not difficult to handle.

Comment: So you are suggesting keeping the code simplest as possible.. even then CUBLAS shall not be faster than mine or that's simply wrong?

Comment: CUBLAS will probably be OK for what you want to do, especially if you want to eventually include other matrix operations.  However, if all you want to do is matrix addition, it's over kill; vector addition is nearly the most trivial CUDA function you can write.

Comment: I agree with Eric. If all you want to do is this vector addition you have shown above, it is ridiculously easy to write by yourself. See my post for how to slice your data and compute using CUDA: http://codeyarns.com/2011/02/16/cuda-work-allocation-techniques/

Answer (score 1):

And since CUBLAS5.0, cublasgeam can be used for that. It computes the weighted sum of 2 optionally transposed matrices.